# localStorage in angular server side rendering losts on browser reload

Tags: angular, local-storage, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-local-storage

I created one application in angular 12. There I used localstorage for storing different values. Then I applied Angular universal in that project. I got many errors related to window, localstorage, etc. So to resolve that I installed **mock browser** and added global variables in `server.ts` like follow:

```
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();
global['window'] = mock.getWindow();
global['document'] = mock.getDocument();
global['localStorage'] = mock.getLocalStorage();
global['navigator'] = mock.getNavigator();
global.DOMParser = window.DOMParser;
```

I have applied `canActivate` on routes and I have applied logic which checks `currentUser` from localStorage. If that exists then return true else false, like below

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
{ path: "user-timeline", component: TimelineComponent,canActivate : [AuthGuard] },
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```
 canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean | UrlTree {
    if (!this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.openConfirmationDialog(route);

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import {LocalstorageService} from "src/app/services/localstorage.service";
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private _localStorage: LocalstorageService,
  ) {}
isLoggedIn() {
    console.log('isLoggedIn',this._localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
    if (this._localStorage.getItem("currentUser")) {
      console.log('isLoggedIn if');
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

**ARTICLE** by [@Santi Barbat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501581/santi-barbat)

I have applied localStorage as per [this](https://santibarbat.medium.com/how-to-use-localstorage-with-angular-9-universal-ssr-517578615637) article. Like mentioned in that article added code in `app.component.ts` and created service `LocalstorageService` with same code. Injected that service and replaced my previous localStorage with this service variable like above used in `auth.service.ts`

It works fine until I manually click on browser reload. When I click on browser reload button, `localStorage` data becomes `undefined`.

Like mentioned in that article, used `isPlatformBrowser` also. Also tried by installing [node-storage-shim](https://github.com/mnahkies/node-storage-shim) for server side rendering and used in local storage service like below

**LocalStorage service**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { AppComponent } from "../app.component";

class LocalStorage implements Storage {
  [name: string]: any;
  readonly length: number;
  clear(): void {}
  getItem(key: string): string | null {
    return undefined;
  }
  key(index: number): string | null {
    return undefined;
  }
  removeItem(key: string): void {}
  setItem(key: string, value: string): void {}
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class LocalstorageService implements Storage {
  private storage: Storage;

  constructor() {
    this.storage = new LocalStorage();

    AppComponent.isBrowser.subscribe((isBrowser) => {
      if (isBrowser) {
        this.storage = localStorage;
      } else {
        const StorageShim = require("node-storage-shim");
        this.storage = new StorageShim();
      }
    });
  }

  [name: string]: any;

  length: number;

  clear(): void {
    this.storage.clear();
  }

  getItem(key: string): string | null {
    return this.storage.getItem(key);
  }

  key(index: number): string | null {
    return this.storage.key(index);
  }

  removeItem(key: string): void {
    return this.storage.removeItem(key);
  }

  setItem(key: string, value: string): void {
    return this.storage.setItem(key, value);
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from "@angular/core";
import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import {isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})
export class AppComponent {

  static isBrowser = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
  
  constructor(public translate: TranslateService,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any) {
  
    AppComponent.isBrowser.next(isPlatformBrowser(platformId));
  }
}
```

In short, in server side rendering I am not able to retain or use localStorage data **on browser relaod**. Also I have observed that if I remove `canActivate` from routes then page reloads and shows data like previous (which is strange)

Is there any way by which I can get localStorage data on browser reload in angular server side rendering?

Or if anyone has any other suggestion/solution for this problem will be of great help.

Please help and guide. Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you simply using `if (typeof window !== 'undefined'){ }` or `if (!isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) { }`? Way easier. `localStorage` from the user's browser isn't available from the server side anyway! If you really want to SSR data based on browser state, use a javascript cookie, as suggested by @Nimród.Barabás

Answer (score 2):

You get the window ,and local storage error because there's no actual browser on the server side , so you have to use cookies instead of local storage for example . I used this approach , you can check the [article](https://www.codesnsolutions.com/cookies-with-angular-ssr/).

Comment: Is cookies the only solution? What if you have data higher than cookies 4kb limit and you need to be able to send to http post body requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use localstorage using `if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.document)` logic, hence you only set it in client side.

Answer (score 0):

- use constructor to initializes the class members
- use ngOnInit to write the code that needs to be executed as soon as class is instantiated

so you can define a method named like: "**initLocalStorage()**" where to put the logic for creating a localStorage.

Comment: Luca.A, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173).

Comment: With the edit this now qualifies for ...

Comment: Luca.A, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Error was like : `EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined` so resolved that after installing mock browser and adding localStorage as a global variable. The link you shared I have also checked that and got @Santi Barbat article which I followed as mentioned in my question still on browser reload and with `canActivate` , page does not reload just tab shows buffering with no API calls in network